# Play Store Update Notification

Tags: android, google-play-services

How does play store client on any android device comes to know that an update is available for an App ?

Is it using Google Cloud Messaging(GCM) for getting update notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, GCM integrated where it will compare  "version code and name" of application used from server, if it is true, notification will be send such as "new application updates available" and it will link to that server.

Comment: GCM supports notifications over HTTP and XMPP. Which one is play store using?